# grunt watch task has different behavior with minified files for several members with same setup in repo

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

**edit for clarity**

old question: grunt watch task leading zeros in minified css for some styles truncated

new diagnosis: There are several people that push to the same repository and I have observed a different behavior to minified files with the same setup of grunt watch.

**end edit**

In my repo I have multiple stylesheets. I use grunt to watch for scss changes and only modify the correlating CSS file. I've had a problem lately where grunt will see a modified file in older, non modified CSS files.

Here's the problem:

I pull from `master`. 
I run `grunt` in the command line. 
I make no changes to a scss file but save the file anyway. 
I stop grunt and `git status`. 
Git sees four modifications in the minified CSS files. 
I save the changes commit and push to a branch. 
When I `git diff` I can see that grunt has removed some of the leading zeros in front of decimal points for opacity.

Here is a screenshot of the diff.

[image: git diff showing truncated leading zero on grunt watch]

If I commit and push these modifications to my branch I can go about making other changes and only modifying the correlating CSS minified files. **But** after merging these changes to `master` and then pulling from `master` again, when I run grunt locally I will see these same four "ghost" modifications with the same zero's being removed in the minified file. I've tried changing my version of node, sass, and grunt but all different versions have the same result!

Has anyone else experienced this or know how to stop grunt from making these changes and bloating the repo with excessive recompiling and commits?

Version of node: 5.1.0
Version of sass: 3.4.19
Version of grunt 0.4.5
Version of grunt cli: 0.1.13

I just recently updated my version of node from 0.10.33 to 5.1.0

And here is my gruntfile:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    // set notifications that run after other tasks
    notify: {
      uglify: {
        options: {
          title: 'Task Complete',
          message: 'Uglify finished running',
        }
      },
      sass: {
        options: {
          title: 'Task Complete',
          message: 'Sass finished running',
        }
      }
    },
    // concat and minify js task
    uglify: {
      site: {
        files: {
          'assets/four/js/site.js': [
            'assets/four/js/src/plugins/*.js',
            'assets/four/js/src/global.js',
            'assets/four/js/src/data/*.js',
            'assets/four/js/src/forms/*.js',
            'assets/four/js/src/modules/*.js',
            'assets/four/js/src/pages/*.js'
          ],
          'assets/four/js/analytics.min.js': ['assets/four/js/src/analytics.js'],
          'assets/four/js/social.js': ['assets/four/js/src/social.js']
        }
      },
      pages: {
        files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['assets/js/pages/**/*.js', '!assets/js/pages/**/*.min.js'], 'assets/js/pages', {
          rename: function(destBase, destPath) {
            return destPath.replace('pageassets/js/pages', destBase).replace('.js', '.min.js');
          }
        })
      }
    },
    //concat and minify scss -> css task
    sass: {
      options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          outputStyle: 'compressed'
      },
      dist: {
          files: {
              'assets/css/style.css': 'assets/css/scss/style.scss',
              'assets/css/old.css': 'assets/css/scss/old.scss',
              'assets/css/pages/brand.css': 'assets/css/pages/scss/brand.scss',
              'assets/css/pages/custom-design-showcase.css': 'assets/css/pages/scss/custom-design-showcase.scss',
              'assets/css/landings.css': 'assets/css/scss/landings.scss',
              // 4.0
              'assets/four/css/site.css': 'assets/four/css/scss/site.scss',
              'assets/four/css/ie.css': 'assets/four/css/scss/ie.scss',
              'assets/four/css/interim.css': 'assets/four/css/scss/interim.scss'
          }
      }
    },
    // compress images losslessly task
    imagemin: {
      dynamic: {
          options: {
              optimizationLevel: 3,
              progressive: true,
              svgoPlugins: [{removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false}]
          },
          files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: 'assets/four/img',
              src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}'],
              dest: 'assets/four/img'
          }]
      }
    },
    // watch for changes in repo and run tasks automatically
    watch: {
      options: {
        // Google Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en
        livereload: true
      },
      html: {
        files: ['templates/default_site/**/*.html']
      },
      js: {
        files: [
                'assets/js/*.js',
                'assets/four/js/src/global.js',
                'assets/four/js/src/plugins/*.js',
                'assets/four/js/src/data/*.js',
                'assets/four/js/src/forms/*.js',
                'assets/four/js/src/pages/*.js',
                'assets/four/js/src/modules/*.js',
                //dont
                '!assets/four/js/*.min.js',
                '!assets/four/js/*.js',
                '!assets/js/*.min.js',
                'assets/js/pages/**/*.js',
                '!assets/js/pages/**/*.min.js',
                'assets/js/geo/**/*.js',
                '!assets/js/geo/**/*.min.js'
                ],
        tasks: ['uglify', 'notify:uglify']
      },
      sass: {
        options: {
          livereload: true
        },
        files: ['assets/css/scss/*.scss', 'assets/four/css/scss/*.scss', 'assets/four/css/scss/pages/*.scss', 'assets/four/css/scss/modules/*.scss', 'assets/css/scss/modules/*.scss', 'assets/css/pages/scss/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:dist', 'notify:sass']
      },
      css: {
        files: ['assets/css/*.css', 'assets/four/css/*.css', 'assets/css/pages/*.css']
      }
    },
  });

  //load plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');

  // to run watch task, enter 'grunt' command line in project DIR
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
Sorry, can you explain me better how you obtain the css file with the zeros? I guess it is correct that grunt-sass with the "compressed" option cuts away the useless zero (there is no difference between opacity:0.5 and opacity:.5)

Comment: Sure thing, @RiccardoDeContardi, the scss files, the ones that are not compiled or compressed have styles that explicitly define a style as `opacity:0.5;`. When I run grunt, it compiles the css file to omit the leading zero `opacity:.5;`. But because the source file, the scss, still have the zero before the decimal, grunt is recompressing the css after each new pull master. You are correct there is no difference between the different formatting to the styles on the page, but I want grunt to leave the zeros in the css (compiled) file so there are no excessive recompiling commits to the repo.

Comment: That's what I don't understand...do you have other css files apart from the ones I see in your grunt task? Or do you modify the css files outside the grunt-sass compiling?

Comment: No, these are the only files that I have, everything is in the grunt file. And I only compile the scss files with grunt, no other modification or pre compiler. I've been going around in circles to try to figure out how this is happening.

Comment: so your workflow is
modify/work on scss > compile > get css (with .5) > commit > push in master, right?

Comment: correct, but also its changing all css files (not just the ones I modified) with the .5 change. and this is only happening to me. And when other people (with the exact same set up, and grunt file) of the repo push to master, their css files have `0.5` so they have to recompile the css after I merge with master. And then when I pull again from master, it starts the cycle again and grunt eliminates the the leading zero and recompiles all of the css files. we generally only work in one css file, so this is adding a lot of bloat to our repo.

Comment: ok now I understand! 
the "0" is the only difference? My first guess is that someone of your team has a slightly different setup somewhere...
Could it be a good idea to put the compiled files into .gitignore? Are they essential or not, as long as you have the source in the repository?

Can I suggest you to modify your question? The essential information is that there are several people that push to the same repository and you observe a different behavior with the same setup.

Comment: Yes, the removing of the zeros is the only difference. Putting some of the compiled files in gitignore is a good idea for now, while I check with the team to make sure all of the environments are the same. Sure thing, I will update the question for clarity. Thank you so much for taking at look at this question. I will update if/when I know more about this.